# ALU Instruction Set

Tags: math, boolean

Question from example in The Elements of Computing Systems, page 37:

The instruction set for the sample ALU has six input/control bits:

1. zx:  if zx then x = 0
2. nx:  if nx then x = !x
3. zy:  if zy then y = 0
4. ny:  if ny then y = !y
5. f:   if f then out = x+y else out = x&y
6. no:  if no then out = !out

For f(x,y) where all the control bits are set to 1, the authors give the ALU output as f(x,y) = 1.

But when I work it out, I get -1.  Zero the bits, negate the bits, add the bits, negate the answer:  111111.... (-1).

Am I missing something with the addition or negation operation?

Thanks.

Comment: `!` is usually not 'negate' (that would be `-`) but 'invert'.

Comment: Thanks - invert then.

Comment: I think the problem is that for the x+y operation there is a carry.  I was doing the function a bit at a time and not carrying.